# ListView,change wrong item view

Tags: android, listview, view

in my application when you click ListView item hidden TextView shows up, and it works well  but the problem is that the text is also displayed in other item that have not been clicked.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            TextView notificationContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_notifi_content_id);

            notificationContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }});
```

From what I have observed onItemClick get view from a few items.
You have ideas how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can record the information of each item in your adapter and deal with your notificationContent in your adapter

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, just add method getView to custom listView adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView != null) {
        TextView notificationContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notifi_content_id);
        notificationContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

by this method when u scroll listView any extension of item will by hidden